# How to fix error as implicit braces are forbidden by coffee-lint checking tool?

Tags: coffeescript, coffeelint

I have simple CoffeeScript code that is working well when integrated with jQuery.
But `coffee-lint` code checking tool shows the following error

> ## coffeelint file.coffee
>
> Implicit braces are forbidden.

My code is

```
$ ->
  $("#selector").dialog
    modal: true
```

What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the minimal change you need. I recommend adding the `()` for the function call, but this rule doesn't care about those.

```
$ ->
  $("#selector").dialog {
    modal: true
  }
```

`modal: true` is implied to be an object. To demonstrate why this rule is good to have enabled, lets say you had some very similar code that accepts a parameter.

```
makeDialog = (foo) ->
  $("#selector").dialog
    modal: true,
    foo: foo,
```

This code looks fine, it even compiles correctly. But at some point you notice that `foo: foo` can be simplified.

```
makeDialog = (foo) ->
  $("#selector").dialog
    modal: true,
    foo,
```

Now your code is broken. CoffeeScript correctly guessed that `modal: true` is a property on an implied object that is the first parameter of `dialog`, but it doesn't know if `foo` is a 2nd property on that object or a 2nd parameter to the function. It ends up compiling out to this:

```
return $("#selector").dialog({ modal: true }, foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a [coffeelint config file](http://www.coffeelint.org/#usage)? If yes, check that no_implicit_braces [policy](http://www.coffeelint.org/#options) has not been changed (defaults to ignore).

Comment: Thank you.But I don't want to change coffeelint.json.
I want to keep default configuration and fix issue.

Comment: Default configuration does not raise any error nor warning for implicit braces. This is why I was asking if you already had a coffeelint.json file, and if it is the case, check that the no_implicit_braces rule is not set to error.